# How to defined dynamic property in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

i want create a array-like class

```
class Demo {
  constructor() {
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach((v, i)=> this[i] = v);
  }
}

let demo = new Demo();

console.log(demo);  // Demo {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}
```

But How can i defined like this in Typescript

Can't access them in ts

```
typescript error:

Property '0' does not exist on type 'Demo'. (2339)
```

Comment: Try inheriting demo from array

Comment: You can define index signature type: `[key: number] : number;`

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `Array` object:

```
class Demo extends Array<number> {
    constructor() {
        super();

        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(v => this.push(v))
    }
}

let a = new Demo();
console.log(a[0]); // 1
a.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

([code in playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Demo%20extends%20Array%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%5D.forEach(v%20%3D%3E%20this.push(v))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20Demo()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(a%5B0%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%201%0D%0Aa.forEach(item%20%3D%3E%20console.log(item))%3B))